# open new entity form with params in crm JS

Tags: javascript, crm

I need to open a new form by clicking a button from task entity and pass the regarding and i need to point on the task i opened the new entity from on field "el_task".
The regarding i weote i working but the task part not.
I created parameters in the crm entity form.
This is what i wrote on task JS file:

```
   function openElRemarkFormButton() {

var parameters = {};
var Regarding = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").getValue();

parameters["parameter_regardingid"] = Regarding[0].id;
parameters["parameter_regardingname"] = Regarding[0].name;
parameters["parameter_regardingtype"] = Regarding[0].entityType;
parameters["parameter_taskName"] = Task.name;
parameters["parameter_taskId"] = Task.id;

//Open the new form
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("el_remark", null, parameters);
```

This is what i wrote on el_remark form:

```
 function OnLoad() {

if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1) {
    var param = Xrm.Page.context.getQueryStringParameters();
    var regardingId = param["parameter_regardingid"];
    var regardingName = param["parameter_regardingname"];
    var regardingType = param["parameter_regardingtype"];
    var taskName = param["parameter_taskName"];
    var taskID = param["parameter_taskId"];
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("el_task").setValue([{ id: taskID, name: taskName }]);

    //Populate the Regarding if there is one
    if (regardingId != "undefined")
    {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("regardingobjectid").setValue([{ id: regardingId, name: regardingName, entityType: regardingType }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if `el_task` is a lookup to Task entity, you need to specify the `entityType` also when you set it.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("el_task").setValue([{ id: taskID, name: taskName, entityType: "task" }]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I wrote it but its nor seems to work. it is not giving any error but the field is empty. I think i need that the subject of the task will appear on this lookup field. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here. You will need to fix the id prior to adding it to your parameter array:

```
parameters["parameter_regardingid"] = Regarding[0].id.replace(/[{}#]/g, "");
```

Also, if you name your parameter attributes identical to the field names on your target form, you will not have to move them in a separate step in your onload event.:

```
parameters["new_fieldnameonTARGETform"] = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_fieldnameonTHISform").getValue();
```

Here are a few help methods I use in building the parameters array prior to calling Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm. I add these as extensions to the ubiquitous Xrm Service Toolkit, but you can put them in your own common lib. Usage follows.

```
toolkit.AddParameter = function (parameters, attributeName, targetAttributeName) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Form and add a parameter to the parameters array. Used with Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm.
    /// Example: XrmServiceToolkit.Common.addParameter(parameters, "new_firstname"); 
    /// <param name="parameters" type="array">
    /// The parameter object array, i.e. var parameters = {};
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="attributeName" type="string">
    /// The name of the field on the source form.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="targetAttributeName" type="string" optional="true">
    /// The name of the field on the target form; not required of the source and target
    /// field names are identical.
    /// </param>
    /// </summary>
    var attribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName);
    if (!toolkit.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute)) {
        if (!toolkit.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.getValue())) {
            parameters[(arguments.length == 3 ? targetAttributeName : attributeName)] = attribute.getValue();
        }
    }
};

toolkit.AddDateParameter = function (parameters, attributeName, targetAttributeName)
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Form and add a date parameter to the parameters array. Used with Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm.
    /// Example: XrmServiceToolkit.Common.addDateParameter(parameters, "new_birthdate", "new_dateofbirth"); 
    /// <param name="parameters" type="array">
    /// The parameter object array, i.e. var parameters = {};
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="attributeName" type="string">
    /// The name of the field on the source form.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="targetAttributeName" type="string" optional="true">
    /// The name of the field on the target form; not required of the source and target
    /// field names are identical.
    /// </param>
    /// </summary>
    var attribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName);
    if (!toolkit.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute)) {
        if (!toolkit.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.getValue())) {
            var dateValue = attribute.getValue();
            parameters[(arguments.length == 3 ? targetAttributeName : attributeName)] = dateValue.getMonth() + '/' + dateValue.getDate() + '/' + dateValue.getFullYear();
        }
    }
};

toolkit.AddLookupParameter = function (parameters, attributeName, targetAttributeName) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Form and add a lookup parameter to the parameters array. Used with Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm.
    /// Example: XrmServiceToolkit.Common.addLookupParameter(parameters, "new_consumerid"); 
    /// <param name="parameters" type="array">
    /// The parameter object array, i.e. var parameters = {};
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="attributeName" type="string">
    /// The name of the field on the source form.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="targetAttributeName" type="string" optional="true">
    /// The name of the field on the target form; not required of the source and target
    /// field names are identical.
    /// </param>
    /// </summary>
    var attribute = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(attributeName);
    if (!toolkit.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute)) {
        if (!toolkit.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.getValue())) {
            parameters[(arguments.length == 3 ? targetAttributeName : attributeName)] = attribute.getValue()[0].id.replace(/[{}#]/g, "");
            parameters[(arguments.length == 3 ? targetAttributeName : attributeName) + "name"] = attribute.getValue()[0].name;
        }
    }
};
```

Usage is:

```
//argument of the openEntityForm().
var parameters = {};

//add values to the parameter array.
XrmServiceToolkit.Common.AddLookupParameter(parameters, "new_opportunityid");
XrmServiceToolkit.Common.AddParameter(parameters, "new_status");
XrmServiceToolkit.Common.AddDateParameter(parameters, "new_startdate");

//open the editor page for this entity type.
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("new_entity", null, parameters);
```